# Get user events from VTune doesn't work with attach to process

Tags: c++, intel-vtune

### TLDR;

I am attempting to run a command line vtune attach to process analysis for some instrumented code with the [application instrumentation lib](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/api-support/instrumentation-and-tracing-technology-apis/basic-usage-and-configuration/instrumenting-your-application.html) supplied by intel. I have succeeded, in collecting user events when running within the vtune application (both command line and GUI). When I use `-target-pid` command line option to connect to the same application, user events do not show up in the profile. The environment setup suggested in [the instructions for attaching to a process](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/api-support/instrumentation-and-tracing-technology-apis/basic-usage-and-configuration/attaching-itt-apis-to-a-launched-application.html) does not work.

### The long version

I have broken this down again and again, and i have hit the minimum amount of things going on here. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with intel vtune installed as part of the oneapi installer package. I have built an example application, which i can share, but it basically spawns threads and does some random computations. I have instrumented the code with `itt` as such:

```
#include <ittnotify.h>

__itt_event cloud_in_event = __itt_event_create( "CloudIn", 7 );

...

void add() {
     __itt_event_start( cloud_in_event );
...
```

This works correctly when run through the gui. Aka, i compile my application with the following:

```
g++ -g -O3 -fno-asm -std=c++17 -I/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/latest/sdk/include -DUSE_THR    example.cpp  -g -o ./example  -lpthread -lm -L/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/sdk/lib64 -littnotify -ldl -D_LINUX
```

I start the gui using:

```
. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh && vtune-gui &
```

Run it using the cpu hotspot analysis in hw mode. The application runs and i get this in the output:

[image]

Yay, my user event is there. All is well.

The equivalent command line also works:

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/bin64/vtune -collect hotspots -knob sampling-mode=hw -knob stack-size=0 -app-working-dir /home/development/example/example --app-working-dir=/home/development/example/example -- /home/development/hovermap/example/example
```

However, if i run the application on its own (using the correct setup for the link path in the environment variables for `INTEL_LIBITTNOTIF`), then attach with the GUI to that process (or with the command line). There are no user events (aka, the `CloudIn` event in the above image) in the profiler data.

If I print out the environment variables in the application, there are quite vast differences in the environments when profiling directly, vs when attaching. For example, there is the following:

```
INTEL_JIT_PROFILER32=/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/lib32/runtime/libittnotify_collector.so
INTEL_JIT_PROFILER64=/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/lib64/runtime/libittnotify_collector.so
ENABLE_JITPROFILING=1
```

Exists in the gui based run environment, but the setup instructional says nothing about these environment variables. I have also tried setting them with no luck.

Any ideas what extra stuff i need to set up?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to attach to application that uses ITT API you need to set up additional environment variables before running it, for example:

```
export INTEL_LIBITTNOTIFY32=/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/lib64/runtime/libittnotify_collector.so
export INTEL_LIBITTNOTIFY64=/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2021.4.0/lib64/runtime/libittnotify_collector.so
./example
```

These environment variables are described in [Attach ITT APIs to a Launched Application](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/api-support/instrumentation-and-tracing-technology-apis/basic-usage-and-configuration/attaching-itt-apis-to-a-launched-application.html) help topic in VTune User Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but at the very start of the question i wrote: 
*The environment setup suggested in the instructions for attaching to a process does not work.*
That text has a link to the same attach ITT APIS link that you linked in your answer. This does not work. There is an open thread with intel [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers/Get-user-events-from-VTune-doesn-t-work-with-attach-to-process/m-p/1294212/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEtRSE83S1JOMlVMWDI0fDEyOTQyMTJ8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M20844). They have reproduced this and are working on it.

Comment: Actually, further on i mention this again: *However, if i run the application on its own (using the correct setup for the link path in the environment variables for `INTEL_LIBITTNOTIF`)*. So this should have been clear enough in the question that this is not the issue.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug with intel, this just doesn't work :(